# Getting "Invalid column name" in trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to create a trigger that will update a column called `TOTAL_CURSOS` from my table `TOTALES` with the number of courses available. The trigger will occur when I insert a value into my table `CURSO`. The problem I have is with my `int` values `DURACION` and `COSTO`.

Here's my trigger code:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER [TR_CURSO] ON [CURSO] FOR INSERT
AS
    
    UPDATE
        TOTALES
    SET
        TOTAL_CURSOS = ( SELECT COUNT(CODIGO) FROM CURSO );
    
    INSERT INTO BITACORA (
        MOMENTO,
        DESCRIPCION
    )
    VALUES (
        SYSDATETIME(),
        
        'SE INSERTO EL MAESTRO CON RFC DE: ' +
        (SELECT RFC_I FROM INSERTED) +
        ' DEL CURSO: ' +
        (SELECT NOMBRE FROM INSERTED) +
        ' CON COSTO DE: '+
        CAST(COSTO AS nvarchar(10) ) +
        ' CON FECHA DE: ' + (GETDATE()) +
        ' CON LA DURACION DE: ' +
        CAST(DURACION AS nvarchar(5)) +
        'Y EL CODIGO DE: ' +
        (SELECT CODIGO FROM INSERTED) +
        ' POR EL USUARIO: ' +
        CAST((CURRENT_USER) AS CHAR)
    );
```

The problem I currently get is that it doesn't recognize DURACION and COSTO as valid columns.

Here is my table structure for CURSO.

```sql
CREATE TABLE CURSO(
    CODIGO                 CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
    NOMBRE                 CHAR(40)  NOT NULL,
    COSTO                  INT       NOT NULL,
    FECHA_INI              DATE      NOT NULL,
    DURACION               INT       NOT NULL,
    RFC_I                  CHAR(13)      NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TOTALES(
    TOTAL_INSTRUCTORES     INT           NULL,
    TOTAL_CURSOS           INT           NULL,
    TOTAL_ESTUDIANTES      INT           NULL
);

CREATE TABLE BITACORA(
    MOMENTO                CHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
    DESCRIPCION            CHAR(150) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Your tables structures? Please post your tables structures, so that many devs will be able to help you with this problem.

Comment: Where should they come from? You’re basically doing an insert with those columns without saying where that are from. Do you want to take them from INSERTED like the other columns?

Comment: Yes, I tried doing the following, INSERTED.COSTO but I get the error that It can't be bound.

Comment: Instead of using a `TRIGGER`, why not used an indexed-view instead? Triggers aren't as reliable as indexed-views which have schemabinding.

Comment: In this particular case I'm supposed to use a trigger.

Comment: @EmmanuelGuerreroHernandez "I'm _supposed_ to use a trigger"? Who is saying that and **why** are they saying that?

Comment: Why are you using fixed-length `char` columns? That's going to cause loads of problems. Especially as you're writing in Spanish (or Portuguese? I apologize) ? You really should be using `nvarchar(...)` for that, otherwise you can't use accented characters reliably.

Comment: Why are the columns in your `TOTALES` table all `int NULL`? Why aren't they `NOT NULL`?

Comment: Class assignment, learning how to implement triggers. I figured out I cannot concatenate int, which Is why I used CAST, but I'm not sure how to properly implement it.

Comment: Your trigger won't work correctly if a multi-row `INSERT` happens btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the insert from values to an insert from select.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TR_CURSO] ON [CURSO]
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE
        TOTALES
    SET
        TOTAL_CURSOS = ( SELECT COUNT(CODIGO) FROM CURSO );
    
    INSERT INTO BITACORA (
      MOMENTO,
      DESCRIPCION
    )
    SELECT 
      SYSDATETIME() AS MOMENTO,
      CONCAT (
        'SE INSERTO EL MAESTRO CON RFC DE: ', RTRIM(RFC_I), 
        ' DEL CURSO: ', RTRIM(NOMBRE), 
        ' CON COSTO DE: ', COSTO, 
        ' CON FECHA DE: ', GETDATE(), 
        ' CON LA DURACION DE: ', DURACION, 
        'Y EL CODIGO DE: ', RTRIM(CODIGO), 
        ' POR EL USUARIO: ', CURRENT_USER
      ) AS DESCRIPCION
    FROM INSERTED;
    
END;
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2e22a6af976e68e1a2a132b2d136e17e)*

Comment: A trigger should always check to see if rows were actually inserted before doing anything. Inserting zero rows will still cause the trigger to execute, which will then update the first table (causing an update trigger to execute if defined), and then inserting zero rows into the second table (causing an insert trigger to execute if defined), and so on.

Comment: @SMor An after insert trigger doesn't run when the insert failed.  See demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try simpler statements and test that they work as expected, then assemble them into more complex sequences. Don't try to optimize before you have a working solution.

For example try this, change these :

```
      CAST(COSTO AS nvarchar(10) ) +
        ' CON FECHA DE: ' + (GETDATE()) +
        ' CON LA DURACION DE: ' +
        CAST(DURACION AS nvarchar(5)) +
```

to:

```
      CAST((SELECT COSTO FROM INSERTED.CURSO) AS nvarchar(10) ) +
        ' CON FECHA DE: ' + (GETDATE()) +
        ' CON LA DURACION DE: ' +
        CAST((SELECT DURACION FROM INSERTED.CURSO) AS nvarchar(5)) +
```

It may work or not. The idea is to find what does work by taking small steps.

Comment: hai @Dai, thx, the idea here is that the op should instead of trying complex statements, test & hack simple ones and assemble the complex one from that

Comment: I was just formatting your code, I wasn't making any point.

Comment: @Dai, I know thats why the thx, & my comment is just to encourage the op to try stuff if the intent is not clear from the terseness of the answer